# Nested 'for' loop not triggered until AFTER first 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform, nested-loops

I'm relatively new to javascript/jquery.

I am trying to run a nested for loop which dynamically creates HTML content which I then append into a table in my body. The first 'for' loop pulls data from Parse, and creates an html table row script, which I then append to a table in html body. The nested 'for' loop should run for each item in the first loop, and create a table row element directly below.

However, for some reason (and I see this when I debug), the first for loop completes before triggering the nested loop. Is there any obvious reason or syntax that is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        var htmlContent = "";
        if (currentUser) {
            console.log(currentUser.get("full_name"));
            $("#user").html(currentUser.get("full_name"));

            var QrUrl = Parse.Object.extend("qr_url");
            var qr_query = new Parse.Query(QrUrl);
            qr_query.equalTo("createdBy", currentUser);
            qr_query.include("createdBy");
            qr_query.ascending("createdAt")

            qr_query.find({
                success: function(qrid_results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < qrid_results.length; i++) { 
                        var qridentry = qrid_results[i];
                        htmlContent="<tr><td>"+qridentry.get("title")+"</td><td>"+"Created"+"</td><td>"+qridentry.createdAt+"</td><td>"+qridentry.get("createdBy").get("full_name")+"</td></tr>";
                        $('#trackingtable').append(htmlContent);

                        var QrLogger = Parse.Object.extend("qr_logger");
                        var qrlog_query = new Parse.Query(QrLogger);
                        qrlog_query.equalTo("qrid", qridentry);
                        qrlog_query.include("createdBy");
                        qrlog_query.include("qrid");

                        qrlog_query.find({
                            success: function(qrlog_results) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < qrlog_results.length; j++) { 
                                    var qrlogentry = qrlog_results[j];
                                    try{
                                        var user_id = obj.get("createdBy").get("full_name");
                                        console.log(user_id);
                                    }
                                    catch(err){
                                        user_id="Unknown Scanner";
                                    }
                                    var dated = qrlogentry.updatedAt;
                                    htmlContent="<tr><td>"+qrlogentry.get("qrid").get("title")+"</td><td>"+"Scanned"+"</td><td>"+dated+"</td><td>"+user_id+"</td></tr>";
                                    $('#trackingtable').append(htmlContent);    
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        //$('#trackingtable').dataTable({   });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `qrlog_query.find` appears to be an asynchronous function.

Comment: You do not really have nested `for` loops here. You need to understand how **asynchronous** interfaces work.

Comment: Is there really no way to restrict this all to work as synchronous functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to make things work with Promises such that they run in the order they would if `find` were synchronous:

```
qr_query.find().then(function(qrid_results) {
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
  for (var i = 0; i < qrid_results.length; i++) { 
    promise = promise.then(function() {
      // Build qrlog_query...
      return qrlog_query.find();
    }).then(function(qrlog_results) {
      for (var j = 0; j < qrlog_results.length; j++) {
        // Do whatever synchronous work you want...
      }
    });
  }
  return promise;
});
```

```

For more info, Google for [javascript promises].

Comment: Thank you! After a few days of breathing async functions, I finally figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the find method surrounding your second for loop is actually deferring execution until whenever that second find completes. If you want the inner for loop to execute synchronously with the first for loop you'll need to structure your code so that either 1. Each deferred execution is chained to start in your desired order. 2. You move all the HTML edits into a separate function that only executes after all qrlog queries have been succefully executed, storing the intermediate results somewhere until you're ready to render your HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately, after hours trying to achieve this, I could not be more confused. I think I am more interested in implementing your first suggestion (chaining the deferred execution). Is this done via 'promises'? If so, can you please help with how this can be done in the for loops?